Is my connection in Jeddha too short?
I am flying from Jakarta to London in August. I have one layover in Jeddah (1 hour 45 mins) then fly to Riyadh where I have another layover of 6 hours before flying to London. I am flying with Saudia Airlines on all flights. Is my layover between Jeddha and Riyadh too short? Will I miss this flight? Also does Saudia transfer baggage or will I have to collect it at each layover?

I am not sure. I have just one booking reference for a round trip.


I have just one booking reference for a round trip.

That sounds like a single ticket.

I have one layover in Jeddah (1 hour 45 mins) then fly to Riyadh where I have another layover

That is an unfortunate routing. The leg from Jeddah to Riyadh is a domestic flight and hence you will probably have to enter Saudi Arabia (and need proper documentation to do so).  You may also have to pick up your bags, pass through customs and re-check them. Exact information about this is hard to find, so I suggest calling the airline and asking with your specific booking info.
For all of this 1:45h seems tight but the airline believes its doable, otherwise they wouldn't have sold you the ticket. If you miss it (due to no fault of your own) Saudia will simply rebook you on the next flight.
Here is the good news: Saudia operates more or less hourly flights from Jeddah to Riyadh so in all likelihood your 1:45h layover in Jeddah will turn  into a 2:45h one, while your layover in Riyadh will only be 5:00h (which is way more than enough).

Might be worthwhile to explicitly point out "proper documentation to enter Saudi Arabia" = "you may need a visa, CHECK THIS NOW".
